# How does this line " return fileNameParts[fileNameParts.length-1]; " work?

Tags: javascript

```
function getFileExtension(i) {

    if (i.indexOf(".") < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    var filenameParts = i.split(".");
    return filenameParts[filenameParts.length-1];

}
```

Here's the whole code. I understand it all except for the last line. I know what it does, but I don't know how or why. The second to last line splits the string at the ".", and then how does the last line actually get all the letters on the right side of the string?

Comment: Do you know how arrays work and how to reference an index? `console.log(filenameParts);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling `var filenameParts = i.split(".");` an array is created containing the different parts. Imagine we use the filename `test.txt` and we use that string to split, we'll get an array like so:

`filenameParts = ["test", "txt"]`

Because the index of the first item in an array is 0, and we need the last item in the array, we call `filenameParts.length-1` to get to the last item.

More information about javascript arrays can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).

Comment: Thank you. Very well explained.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to mark my post as answer if it did answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

The `.split()` function returns an **array** of strings, not a string. The expression `filenameParts[filenameParts - 1]` fetches the last element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`filenameParts.length` delivers the count of the `filenameparts`, split in the line above. `filenameParts[number]` delivers the one item of the array, which is positioned at `number`. `-1` because arrays start at 0 not at 1. So it delivers the last item of the array. Clear?

Answer (score 1):

`filenameParts` is an array and you read a single value with it's index. A value in this case is one part of the string between the ".".

`filenameParts.length` is equal to the count of values inside the array. As an array index starts with 0 you have to subtract 1 to get the index of the last value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function `getFileExtension` is designed to return the file extension of a given file. For example `getFileExtension('image.gif')` would return `gif`.

In the line (given that `i` is set to `image.gif`):

```
var filenameParts = i.split(".");
```

`filenameParts` will be an array, where `image.gif` has been split on the period. So `filenameParts = ['image', 'gif']` where element zero is `image` and element one is `gif`. Remember that array indices are zero-based!

In the last line:

```
return filenameParts[filenameParts.length-1];
```

the function itself will return the last element in the `filenameParts` array (['image', 'gif']) which is `gif`. The part `filenameParts.length-1` says get the length of the `filenameParts` array (which is 2), subtract 1 (which is 1), and return that element of the `filenameParts` array. So we return `filenameParts[1]` which is the last element of the array (remember, array indices are zero-based).

To get the last element of the array we could also have done

```
return filenameParts.pop();
```

because the `pop()` function returns the last element of an array.

Answer (score 1):

`var filenameParts = i.split('.')` returns an array of made of the splitted elements of `i`

```
filenameParts[filenameParts.length-1];
```

select the last element of that array